# Extract patterns with regular expression in Python

Tags: python

I have a list string, and I want extract three patterns and form a dataframe. Each string has three part, first part, `s_` or `t_q_` or NaN; the middle pattern could be any letter, number  and _, but cannot end with `abc`; last part, should be `abc` or NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import re

str_list = ['s_c45abc','s_ab00_a','t_q_de45abc','t_q_123','t_q_c34b7_da','456a','456abc','456b']

pd.Series(str_list).str.extract(r"(s_|t_q_)?(\w+[^(abc)])(abc)?")


    0       1         2
0   s_      c45       abc
1   s_      ab00_     NaN
2   t_q_    de45      abc
3   t_q_    123       NaN
4   t_q_    c34b7_d   NaN
5   NaN     456       NaN
6   NaN     456       abc
7   NaN     456       NaN
```

However, the second/fifth/sixth/last rows are incorrect. The true result should be

```
    0       1             2
0   s_      c45           abc
1   s_      ab00_a        NaN
2   t_q_    de45          abc
3   t_q_    123           NaN
4   t_q_    c34b7_da      NaN
5   NaN     456a          NaN
6   NaN     456           abc
7   NaN     456b          NaN
```

Comment: What happens if you have a string like "abcabc"?

Comment: @justhecuke Thank you for your question. If it's 'abcabc', the split should be `NaN`, `abc`, `abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made some mistakes in your regex which imply that you do not know how regular expressions work. You should review the regular expression [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to make sure you understand what all of the parts are doing.

```
(s_|t_q_)?(\w+[^(abc)])(abc)?
```

First off, `[^(abc)]` matches a single character that is not `(`, `a`, `b`, `c`, or `)`. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/670693 for how to match a string which does not contain a specific substring, not that you need to, but it seems relevant to what you were trying to do.

What you want to do is pretty odd, but possible to a certain extent. Your `(s_|t_q_)?` seems fine. The `(\w+[^(abc)])` is wrong as I've stated before, but it needs to be modified to `(\w+?)??` to do a non-greedy `??` 0-or-1 match. This is because your end `(abc)?` is enough to make sure that `(\w+?)??` does not match "abc" at the end, but only if you only have one "abc" at the end. If you have ".*abcabc" then your column 1 will end with "abc" and your column 2 will be "abc" as well. In the case of just "abc" you need the `??` so that your output is `NaN, NaN, abc`.

This leaves you with

```
^(s_|t_q_)?(\w+?)??(abc)?$
```

If you want to make sure that `all(e[-3:] != 'abc' for e in df[1] if type(e) is float and not math.isnan(e)) == True`, then you need to modify your regex to:

```
^(s_|t_q_)?(\w+?)??(abc)*$
```

The key changes here are to `(abc)*` where we capture as many `abc` strings at the end as we can. The existing `??` for `(\w+?)??` should be enough to make sure that part works as expected.